# Arduino UNO + Enc28j60 + DHT11 +PHP & Mysql (LAN MODE)

Tags: arduino, webclient

I'm a arduino newbie, I would like to build an web project for my thesis.
I use arduino uno as microcontroller, DHT11 for temperature sensor and Enc28j60 for the ethernet shield.
The project is used to control LED and monitor the temperature and humidity through a website.
I want to set arduino as client.
I want to simulate this project in LAN mode.
I want to ask:
1. how to set arduino as client?
2. how to receive the temperature data from the arduino and store it to the database(mysql)?
3. how to control led via website?

I had tried arduino as server, and it is succeed.
But I confuse how to set it as client
thank you,

anyone  can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a web server on the computer, and have the Arduino make a GET or POST request to a script (e.g. PHP) on the server that saves values to the database. You could also get the server to return a value that indicates whether the LED should be on or off. More details are found in the Arduino help: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetClient

To get the LED to respond quickly in this setup would require the Arduino to continuously poll the script however, which doesn't seem ideal. Why do you want the Arduino to be the client?

Answer (score 0):

because I need to store the temperature data to the database. If I set arduino as a server. I dont know how to store the data to the database. I still dont understand about to control my lamp if i set the arduino as webclient